# Reset content in FLash AS2 scrollpane component to top

Tags: flash, scrollpane

I have a scrollpane component that I need to force to the top on certain moments. That is, if the person scrolled to the middle but selects a button outside the scrollpane, I need the content to be at the top. Is there a way to do this in AS2???

Thanks!

Peter

Answer (score 1):

I put the component in the first frame of a new symbol ('container'), with `stop()`, and made a second frame empty, with `gotoAndStop(1)`. So in the buttom outside the panel, you put the string `container.gotoAndStop(2)` besides the another actions, so you can force the scroll to reinitialize.